# Failing to get my XML doc to removeChild

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, removechild

I'm having a problem removing an XML element from my doc.  I have searched the forums and I think I'm doing things properly, please can you help shed some light on where I'm screwing up?

I have an array containing IDs which I'm looping through.  Within that loop I'm looping through the XML doc to find elements whose "myId" attribute has the same ID as in the array.
When I find one I want to remove that element from the XML doc.

Here's my code:

```
var xmlFilename=document.getElementById('xmlFilename').value;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",xmlFilename,false);
    xmlhttp.send();
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

    // lets get all the xml elements into xAll
    var xAll=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('*');
    // lets use the buttonList array - this corresponds to the elements in the xml to hide

    for (var i=0; i<buttonList.length;i++) {
        alert ("Looking for "+buttonList[i]);
        //find the XML node with the same id
        for(var j=0;j<xAll.length;j++) {
            y=xAll[j];
            if (y.getAttribute('myId')==buttonList[i]) {
                alert('Found a match');
                xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(y);
                alert('removed');
            } 
        }
        alert('next!');
    }
    alert('all done');
```

It loops through as expected, but when it finds a match the xmlDoc.documentElement.removeChild(y); 
line causes the script to fail and it never gets to 'removed' state.

I am grateful for any help/pointers in the right direction.

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Can you pastebin a snippet of the xml ? You are removing the child from `documentElement` - but are these nodes direct children of the `root` node?

Comment: Sample XML:
`<doc>
 <section>
  <sectionTitle>Profile</sectionTitle>
  <sectionPreamble>This is the intro text</sectionPreamble>
  <sectionStatement myId="1">Awesome statement</sectionStatement>
  <sectionStatement myId="2">I am a statement</sectionStatement>
  <sectionStatement myId="3">I am another statement</sectionStatement>
  <sectionPostscript>This is the exit text</sectionPostscript>
 </section>
</doc>`

The elements with a MyId may appear at different levels within the XML.

Comment: Indeed you are removing a node that is not directly a child of `documentElement` and that is why it's failing.  See the answer posted by Yoshi for a fix.

Comment: Thanks Kami - this is a fine example of me cutting and pasting stuff from tutorials/forums without fully understanding what it does!  You are absolutely right, and thanks for asking me to post the XML.

Comment: @MarkStanley for future reference, when you need to add information like that it's better to edit the question rather than post the information in a comment, as that allows you to use proper formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
var i = 0, j, y;
for (; i < buttonList.length; i += 1) {
  // Running "backwards" is done on purpose, as `xAll` is a "live" NodeList.
  // If otherwise, you'd run into problems regarding wrong indexes. 
  for(j = xAll.length - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
    y = xAll[j];
    if (y.getAttribute('myId') == buttonList[i]) {
      y.parentNode.removeChild(y);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Yoshi - a worked example of Ian's answer.  I like the added advice on running the inner loop backwards too.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByTagName` can find elements at all levels of the DOM tree, not just direct children of the document element.  Rather than trying to remove `y` from the `documentElement` you need to get y's parent node (which might be the document element or might be deeper down the tree) and then remove `y` from *that*.